# Why It taking long time to process? My page keeps on loading for hours ?

Tags: php, laravel, routes

Added the Route to clear the cache. My page keeps on loading -

```
Route::get('/clear-all', function() {
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('route:clear');
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('view:clear');
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('config:cache');
        $exitCode = Artisan::call('optimize');
        exec('composer dump-autoload');
        return '<h1>All cache cleared</h1>';
    });
```

Comment: if you are using laravel 5.6, it doesn't have the optimize command anymore

Comment: I Am using laravel 5.5.40